# Multiple Instances of Async MediaCodec Android Decoders to use all Hardware Decoders H.264

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediacodec

To understand whether there is any benefit in using multiple async-based MediaCodec decoders on Android smartphones.

With an aim to improve decoding performance, I implemented two or say `N<4` MediaCodec based async decoders using multiple threads.

For instance for 1080P resolution, the decoder was able to achieve a decoding speed  of around 250 FPS (this does not include screen rendering, purely decoding speed.). However, decoder performance did not improve when compared between using 1 decoder versus 2 decoders.

The rationale behind implementing multiple async decoders was to use multiple hardware decoders that are available in modern COTS.

Could any confirm these numbers or shed light on whether using multiple threads of async decoders has any benefit? If not, how do I make use of all the hardware decoders.

My plan was to send different GoPs (group of pictures) to different async decoders with the hope of improving decoding speed.